# League of legends

Tags: software-installation, wine, games, playonlinux

I'm having trouble installing League of Legends with playonlinux on ubuntu 16.04.

I have had no luck so far with playonlinux. I manage to get to 30-40% progress on the install (sometimes more) before getting a bugsplat. I am constantly getting these bugsplats even though I have tried to install several different ways.

Could someone give me a detailed tutorial on how to install LoL? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should be able to remove bugsplat error:

Go to terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

1. Get Root Access:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```

Write your password then turn off the timestamps which were causing problems to all Ubuntu players with this line:

2. Make sure you're writing as `root@`:

   ```
   echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps
   ```
3. Next make sure you make it permanent, leave root@ by writing `exit` then enter, then write `sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` then add the line `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0` to the file

Comment: Could this have any negative side effects in the handshake for the previously received SYN+ACK?

Comment: @ThatGuy No, nothing will happen. timestamps only give you timelength for every transmission and retransmission (current mean).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Play on Linux scripts are updated more slowly than they should be. I have found this script to be on the cutting edge of the WineHQ community:

https://github.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends